# Pagination bug leading to empty pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, pagination

One of the users on CogSci [reported a bug where pagination failed at 15, 30 and 50 items per page](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/401/paging-fails-at-15-30-and-50-items-per-page). He linked to a [similar bug on Biology](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275/paging-fails-at-50-items-per-page-when-ordered-by-newest).

Here is the bug report from [jonsca](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/159165/jonsca):

> To reproduce:
>
> - Go to the `Questions` link/tab
> - Select the last page (in our case, page #9 with 50 questions per page)
> - Now, try to go back the page before that one (page #8)
>
> I get the following:
>
> [image]
>
> Unlike when I had the problem on Biology.SE, this seems to occur with
>   15 or 30 items per page selected as well.
>
> I'm using Chrome 20, but I can reproduce the problem on Firefox 13.

I am able to reproduce this on Chrome 20.0.1132.57 on Mac OS X 10.7.4.

Is this a caching issue? Can this be fixed?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UjhhD.png !

Comment: I don't think this is something I can meddle with ;)

Comment: No, but by commenting saying you can repro, the team knows this is srs bsnss!

Comment: They're not just missing...they're out of order! See http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions?page=4&sort=votes . Ordered by votes the questions go "16, 0, -7" and then the next page is back to 16! It's gone mad I tell you, **mad!**

Comment: I've seen this on occasion for at least the past few months, though not worked so hard to get a reproducible test case.  For testing, be wary of ignored tags clouding the issue as they can produce the same effect under the right circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's just annoying! Some glitch; it wouldn't be very interesting to go into details, other that to say "it didn't quite do what we wanted it to". It is being a bit more obedient now, I think.

Comment: But now how will I know which of my completely baseless and speculative explanations was the most incorrect?! Well, I suppose as long as it's fixed...